# What is the difference between OracleDataSourceFactory, OracleConnectionPoolDataSource and OracleDataSource?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

What is the difference between `OracleDataSourceFactory`, `OracleConnectionPoolDataSource` and `OracleDataSource`? What are the different situations you would use them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there is a [`OracleDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/datasource/OracleDataSource.html) and a [`OracleConnectionPoolDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.html) is because the JDBC standard defines two types of connections:

- [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html) which are commonly used in JDBC applications
- [`javax.sql.PooledConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/PooledConnection.html) are not directly used by applications by by connection pool vendors

[`OracleDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/datasource/OracleDataSource.html) is a factory of [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html) objects and that's the datasource that's widely used by applications. On the other hand [`OracleConnectionPoolDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.html) is used for [`javax.sql.PooledConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/PooledConnection.html) and is used only in connection cache implementations (UCP for example).

You can safely ignore `OracleDataSourceFactory` which is an artifact to build DataSource objects that Oracle no longer promotes.

With the 19c Oracle JDBC driver, you would instantiate a datasource like this:

```
oracle.jdbc.datasource.OracleDataSource ds = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
```

or, if you're using the replay driver (for [Application Continuity](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability/app-continuity.html)):

```
oracle.jdbc.datasource.OracleDataSource ds = oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl();
```